# User-defined items in MFC CTreeCtrl

Tags: c++, tree, mfc

At the moment we are using Stingray controls in our project. The following image shows a tree with various sized icons.

[image]

Now we want to replace the Stingray controls by MFC Controls. Is there a possibility to control the size and position of an item in CTreeCtrl in order to realize a tree with icons in different sizes?

It would be nice if you could provide a c++ code snippet.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This would require [custom drawing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/custom-draw) the control. But even then, the system will use a single font to calculate the layout and spacing for all items. I don't think there is a way to make the individual items have different heights (which would make for a noisy, distractful UI anyway). Here is an old (possibly outdated) [sample](https://web.archive.org/web/20060427195809/https://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;q248496).

Comment: MFC controls for the most part just wrap the functionality of Win32 controls; they provide extensions for some few cases, but not for `CTreeCtrl`. So you should check the documentation of [Tree-View controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/tree-view-controls). Unlike other controls, Tree-View doesn't support owner-draw (`WM_MEASUREITEM/WM_DRAWITEM`), I believe because items can be editable. The icons in tree-view controls are members of an [Image-List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/image-lists), of which all images are of the same size.